# How to get ID when you pass my ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that gets passed the document object like:

```
toggle( $('username') );


function Toggle(id)
{
  ///  ??

}
```

How can I get the actual name of the object passed i.e. username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, can't you:

```
$(id).attr("id");
```

or

```
$(id).attr("name");
```

Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Why can't I just do   alert( id.id);  ??  I guess the $('') object is different than when you do getelementbyID('');

Comment: Where can I get a reference for all the methods/properties for the object $('') ?

Answer (score 1):

Either what [Jonathon said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511630/how-to-get-id-when-you-pass-my-id/511656#511656) or with

```
$(id).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

The object that gets passed in is an instance of the jQuery object, which contains a set of elements (in this case with only one element in it).  The documentation is on the [jQuery documentation site](http://docs.jquery.com/Core).

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery object that `$()` returns, wraps one *or more* DOM elements.
Using the accessors `$().attr()`, `$().val()`, `$().text()` and `$().html()` will act on the first of those wrapped elements.
If you want to drop out of jQuery mode so that you can work with the native DOM element (sometimes useful) use `$().get( index )`.

eg

```
var el = $('#mytextbox').get(0);
el.value = 'a new value';
alert(el.id);
etc...
```